# Java asking for return statement for class

Tags: java, class, return

I have the following code:

```
public class BinaryDecoder{
public static void main(String[] args){
    String binNum = "110101"; 
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i<binNum.length();i++){
        //res += parseDigit(binNum.charAt(i),binNum);
    }
//  System.out.println(res);

}
public static int parseDigit(int index, String binNum){
    switch (binNum.charAt(index)){
        case 0:
        break;
        case 1:
        int val = (int) Math.pow(2,-index+binNum.length());
        return val;
        }
}

}
```

And I am getting the error: BinaryDecoder.java:30: error: missing return statement
}
^

I may have interpreted this wrong, but why would my class BinaryDecode have or even need a return statement? Is there something else wrong with the code?

Note: I am fairly new in java, so sorry if there are any obvious errors in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class isn't what needs a return statement, the `parseDigit` method is. In its signature, it claims to return an `int`. You *do* have a `return` statement for that method, but because it is inside a switch statement, it isn't guaranteed to happen.

Answer (score 5):

It's not the *class* that needs a return statement; it is the `parseDigit` function, which you have declared as returning an `int`. It is an error to have the possibility of not returning a value when you have said it will.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has to do with your `parseDigit` class.

If the case is 0, there is no return and the compiling fails. Try this:

```
public static int parseDigit(int index, String binNum){
    switch (binNum.charAt(index)){
        case 0:
        return SOMETHING;
        break;
        case 1:
        int val = (int) Math.pow(2,-index+binNum.length());
        return val;
        default:
        return -1;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: And what if `val != 0 && val != 1`?